# Spring Data JPA Returning Proxy Object For One Record and Real Object For One Record

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, proxy, spring-data-jpa

I am using `spring-data-jpa` to read data from db.

**JPA Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ICM_STATUSES")
public class IcmMdStatuses implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "STATUS_INTERNAL_IDENTIFIER")
    private long statusInternalIdentifier;

    @Column(name = "STATUS_IDENTIFIER")
    private String statusIdentifier;

    @Column(name = "STATUS_NAME")
    private String statusName;

    @Column(name = "STATE_NAME")
    private String stateName;

    @Column(name = "IS_ACTIVE")
    private String isActive= "Y";

    @Column(name = "CREATED_BY")
    private String createdBy;

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(name = "CREATE_DATE")
    private Date createdDate;

    @Column(name = "UPDATED_BY")
    private String updatedBy;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "UPDATE_DATE")
    private Date updateDate;
}
```

**JPA Repository**

```
public interface StatusRepository extends JpaRepository<IcmMdStatuses, Long> {
    Optional<IcmMdStatuses> findByStatusIdentifier(String statusIdentifier);
}
```

**DB Table Data**
[image: DB Table Data]

**Problem:**

If I try to fetch `Open` status record. I am getting Hibernate Proxy Object instead of real object.
[image: Open Status Proxy]

If I try to fetch `Reopen` status record. i am getting real object.
[image]

Except for `Open` status, for the rest all statuses i am getting real objects.

I could able to get the real object using `Hibernate.unproxy(-)`
[image]

**Problem**

```
MyEntity entity = new MyEntity();
//If i use any other status except Open the below line saves pk of that particular status.           
entity.setFromStatus(statusRepository.findByStatusIdentifier("Open"));//saving null in db
entity.setToStatus(statusRepository.findByStatusIdentifier("Reopen"));//saving value 93(PK of Reopen status)  
myRepo.save(entity);
```

Please help to understand what's the actual issue, as i am experiencing this issue only for `Open` Status, rest all works as expected.

Comment: Why is this an issue?

Comment: @JensSchauder, I need to explicitly convert the proxy to real object, which i don't want. To Add I am seeing this behavior only for `Open` status record.

Comment: Why do you have to convert the proxy? And why don't you want that? Entities being sometimes proxies with JPA is perfectly normal with JPA.

Comment: I just updated the question with actual problem. please check once.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is most probably due to open-session-in-view and the fact that you loaded some other object that refers to this `Open` status object. Since that other object did not load the `Open` status object, it created a proxy for it which is then part of the persistence context. The next time you load that object, you retrieve that proxy instead of the real object because Hibernate must maintain the object identity guarantee for a persistence context.

Comment: OSIV is completely unrelated to this, I think.

Comment: I have seen such problems very often before. The fact that the persistence context spans across the whole request can lead to this issue. There is even a possibility that you explicitly fetch join an association yet you still receive a proxy if the container object is already part of the persistence context. My usual suggestion is to clear the persistence context after simple reads to avoid this.

Comment: @ChristianBeikov, I am not that familiar with OSIV. To give more clarity, even with the first time request, i am getting proxy object. I understand for subsequent requests Hibernate can store it in persistent context. But it should give the real object at least for the first time.

Comment: What do you mean by "first request" specifically? You have to understand that OSIV makes the persistence context span for the whole HTTP request.

Comment: How do you know the OP has OSIV? I do not see it in their code above. I am not using OSIV and have a similar issue, where I JOIN FETCH in an @Query and it is returning a Proxy instead of actually FETCHING what I fetched. There is no persistence context with object before I run this query.

Comment: I don't know for sure if OSIV is at play, but since it's enabled by default in Spring, that's my first assumption. When a query returns a proxy for a join fetched association, this is usually because you have the proxy already in your persistence context before running the query. Try clearing it with `EntityManager.clear()` before running the query.